# How to hide asp.net wizard control step name?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to hide step name in left bar. Don't want to visible 'Wizardstep1','Wizardstep2' and 'Wizardstep3'. Can somebody show me how to do this?

[image]

```
     <asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="MyWizard" OnNextButtonClick="MyWizard_NextButtonClick"
                        Width="640px" Height="200px" OnFinishButtonClick="MyWizard_FinishButtonClick">
                        <WizardSteps>
                        <asp:WizardStep ID="Wizardstep1" runat="server" StepType="Start">
                        </asp:WizardStep>
                        <asp:WizardStep ID="Wizardstep2" runat="server" StepType="Step">
                        </asp:WizardStep>
                        <asp:WizardStep ID="Wizardstep3" runat="server" StepType="Finish">
                        </asp:WizardStep>
     </asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a property DisplaySideBar that you can set to false.

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" ID="MyWizard" OnNextButtonClick="MyWizard_NextButtonClick" Width="640px" Height="200px" OnFinishButtonClick="MyWizard_FinishButtonClick">
     ....
</asp:Wizard>
```

Also, it is possible to set a custom template for it. Maybe you can set it to empty if above approach didn't work:

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="MyWizard" OnNextButtonClick="MyWizard_NextButtonClick" Width="640px" Height="200px" OnFinishButtonClick="MyWizard_FinishButtonClick">
     <sidebartemplate>
     </sidebartemplate>
     ....
</asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting:

```
 <asp:WizardStep Title=""></asp:WizardStep>
```

Also, [DisplaySideBar="false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.displaysidebar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
 <asp:Wizard DisplaySideBar="false"></asp:Wizard>
```